# 2D kernel calling and launch parameters for non-square matrix

Tags: cuda, 2d, nested-loops, flatten

I am attempting to port the following (simplified) nested loop as a CUDA 2D kernel. The sizes of `NgS` and `NgO` will increase with larger data sets; for now I just want to get this kernel to output the correct results for all values:

```
// macro that translates 2D [i][j] array indices to 1D flattened array indices
#define idx(i,j,lda) ( (j) + ((i)*(lda)) )

int NgS  = 1859;
int NgO  = 900;

// 1D flattened matrices have been initialized as:
 Radio_cpu = new double [NgS*NgO];
Result_cpu = new double [NgS*NgO];
// ignoring the part where they are filled w/ data

for (m=0; m<NgO; m++) {        
    for (n=0; n<NgS; n++) {
            Result_cpu[idx(n,m,NgO)]] = k0*Radio_cpu[idx(n,m,NgO)]];
    }
}
```

The examples I have come across usually deal with square loops, and I have been unable to get the correct output for all the GPU array indices compared to the CPU version. Here is the host code calling the kernel:

```
dim3 dimBlock(16, 16);
dim3 dimGrid;
dimGrid.x = (NgO + dimBlock.x - 1) / dimBlock.x;
dimGrid.y = (NgS + dimBlock.y - 1) / dimBlock.y;

// Result_gpu and Radio_gpu are allocated versions of the CPU variables on GPU
trans<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(NgO, NgS, k0, Radio_gpu, Result_gpu);
```

Here is the kernel:

```
__global__ void trans(int NgO, int NgS,
                      double k0, double * Radio, double * Result) {

int n = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int m = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

if(n > NgS || m > NgO) return;

// map the two 2D indices to a single linear, 1D index
int grid_width = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
int idxxx = m + (n * grid_width);

Result[idxxx] = k0 * Radio[idxxx];
}
```

With the current code, I proceeded to compare the `Result_cpu` variable with `Result_gpu` variable once copied back. When I cycle through the values I get:

```
    // matches from NgS = 0...913
    Result_gpu[NgS = 913][NgO = 0]: -56887.2
    Result_cpu[Ngs = 913][NgO = 0]: -56887.2

    // mismatches from NgS = 914...1858
    Result_gpu[NgS = 914][NgO = 0]: -12.2352
    Result_cpu[NgS = 914][NgO = 0]: 79448.6
```

This pattern is the same, irregardless of the value of `NgO`. I have been trying to figure out where I have made a mistake by looking at various examples for a few hours and trying out changes, but so far this scheme has worked minus the obvious issue at hand whereas the others have caused kernel invocation errors/left the GPU array uninitialized for all values. Since I clearly cannot see the mistake, I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction towards a fix. I'm pretty sure it's right under my nose and I can't see it.

In case it matters, I'm testing this code on a Kepler card, compiling using MSVC 2010, CUDA 4.2 and 304.79 driver and have compiled the code with both `arch=compute_20,code=sm_20` and `arch=compute_30,code=compute_30` flags with no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@vaca_loca: I tested the following kernel (it works for me also with non-square block dimensions):

```
__global__ void trans(int NgO, int NgS,
                  double k0, double * Radio, double * Result) {

int n = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int m = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
if(n > NgO || m > NgS) return;
int ofs = m * NgO + n;
Result[ofs] = k0 * Radio[ofs];
}

void test() {

int NgS  = 1859, NgO  = 900;
int data_sz = NgS * NgO, bytes = data_sz * sizeof(double);
cudaSetDevice(0);
double *Radio_cpu = new double [data_sz*3],
    *Result_cpu = Radio_cpu + data_sz,
    *Result_gpu = Result_cpu + data_sz;
double k0 = -1.7961233;

srand48(time(NULL));
int i, j, n, m;
for(m=0; m<NgO; m++) {
  for (n=0; n<NgS; n++) {
        Radio_cpu[m + n*NgO] = lrand48() % 234234;
        Result_cpu[m + n*NgO] = k0*Radio_cpu[m + n*NgO];
    }
}

double *g_Radio, *g_Result;
cudaMalloc((void **)&g_Radio, bytes * 2);
g_Result = g_Radio + data_sz;
cudaMemcpy(g_Radio, Radio_cpu, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 dimBlock(16, 16);
dim3 dimGrid;
dimGrid.x = (NgO + dimBlock.x - 1) / dimBlock.x;
dimGrid.y = (NgS + dimBlock.y - 1) / dimBlock.y;

trans<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(NgO, NgS, k0, g_Radio, g_Result);

cudaMemcpy(Result_gpu, g_Result, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(m=0; m<NgO; m++) {
    for (n=0; n<NgS; n++) {
        double c1 = Result_cpu[m + n*NgO],
                c2 = Result_gpu[m + n*NgO];
        if(std::abs(c1-c2) > 1e-4)
            printf("(%d;%d): %.7f %.7f\n", n, m, c1, c2);
    }
}
cudaFree(g_Radio);
delete []Radio_cpu;
}
```

though, in my opinion, accessing data from global memory using quads might not be very cache-friendly since access stride is pretty large. You might consider using 2D textures instead if it's critical for your algorithm to access data in 2D locality

Comment: I thought that was it also, but when I interchange the variables in the conditional statement, I get a kernel launch error and thus all the Result_GPU values are 0.

Comment: I'm attempting to debug with printf statements in the kernel to see how the indices are wrong in the meantime. I feel like there might be multiple problems -- I might not be calling the kernel correctly AND I might not be indexing in the kernel correctly.

Comment: I edited my answer: have a look at it again, this works fine for me

Comment: Your ofs definition was one of the first things I tried and it didn't work for me -- it started mostly working when I added the changes from this example: http://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/wiki/TutorialMultidimensionalKernelLaunch

Comment: I think I might have figured out the problem by running that example a few times -- seems like blocksize.x and blocksize.y should have a factor in common with the corresponding num_elements_x and num_elements_y, but I still have to test this idea in the actual code.

Comment: Meh, don't think that was it either, I'll have to do more testing with a sample matrix and keep increasing the size until I find out what the problem is.

Comment: ok I reposted the whole program I played with, I hope moderators won't delete it because of length: if it's not working for you, then I probably don't understand the question

Comment: awesome, thank you, I will try it out and see if I can find the error in my own code

Comment: Just wanted to say this worked great. The problem I was having was that I forgot to disclose one important detail -- for simplification, I initialized the arrays here as double, In the actual code, I was initializing the arrays as cuDoubleComplex types. (oops!) Apparently when using arrays of structs, the indexing used in this example breaks. I'm satisfied just using 2 variables to represent complex numbers for now, but it would be nice to know how to fix this example so that it works with cuDoubleComplex structs or any other struct, for that matter. Again, deeply in thanks asm!

Comment: for that you can parameterize your kernel with a number type NT:
template < class NT >
__global__ void trans(int NgO, int NgS,NT k0, NT * Radio, NT * Result);
  then the kernel call would look like: trans< NT ><<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>trans(...).  You might also need to provide an operator __device__ NT operator *(const NT& a, const NT& b) if there is no one available for your number type

Comment: I think I get it now -- this made it a little clearer: http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/cuda-template-kernels/ For now I will just leave the complex numbers as two separate variables, but once I get it fully working I will give parameterization like you mention a shot. Thanks again!!!